# Issues with zookeeper

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I have certain issues with zookeeper.

1) It is not able to create `zookeeper_server.pid` in my datadir. I have also tried the suggestion of manually creating the myid in the datadir plus rwx permission is given recursively. But, still getting the following error while stopping the zookeeper:

```
 datadir = dataDir=/usr/local/hadoop/zookeeper/snapshot
error: could not find file /usr/local/hadoop/zookeeper/snapshot
```

2) I was trying to manage the zookeeper manually while installing the `HBASE`. So due to previous issue it was not able to launch even a single instance.

```
2013-08-26 12:29:28,908 - INFO  [main:QuorumPeerConfig@310] - Defaulting to majority quorums
2013-08-26 12:29:28,917 - FATAL [main:QuorumPeerMain@83] - Invalid config, exiting abnormally
org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig$ConfigException: Error processing /home/ubuntu/zookeeper/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:110)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:99)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:76)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: /home/ubuntu/zookeeper/snapshot/myid file is missing
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parseProperties(QuorumPeerConfig.java:320)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:106)
    ... 2 more
Invalid config, exiting abnormally
```

3) I also tried the `HBASE` managed zookeeper. But, in that also even a single instance of zookeeper was not able to launch and was throwing the following error:

```
zkserver3: java.io.IOException: Could not find my address: slave1 in list of ZooKeeper quorum servers
zkserver3:  at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.HQuorumPeer.writeMyID(HQuorumPeer.java:140)
zkserver3:  at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.HQuorumPeer.main(HQuorumPeer.java:61)
zkserver2: java.io.IOException: Could not find my address: slave in list of ZooKeeper quorum servers
zkserver2:  at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.HQuorumPeer.writeMyID(HQuorumPeer.java:140)
zkserver2:  at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.HQuorumPeer.main(HQuorumPeer.java:61)
starting master, logging to /home/ubuntu/hbase/logs/hbase-ubuntu-master-ip-10-164-98-114.out
rgserver3: starting regionserver, logging to /home/ubuntu/hbase/bin/../logs/hbase-ubuntu-regionserver-ip-XXXXXXX.out
rgserver2: starting regionserver, logging to /home/ubuntu/hbase/bin/../logs/hbase-ubuntu-regionserver-ip-XXXXXXX.out
rgserver1: starting regionserver, logging to /home/ubuntu/hbase/bin/../logs/hbase-ubuntu-regionserver-ip-XXXXXX.out
```

**Updated logs for issue 1**

```
JMX enabled by default
Using config: /usr/local/hadoop/zookeeper/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... 
/usr/local/hadoop/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh: 80: /usr/local/hadoop/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh: cannot create /usr/local/hadoop/zookeeper/snapshot
# The number of snapshots to retain in dataDir/zookeeper_server.pid: Directory nonexistent
STARTED
hduser@naresh-pc:/usr/local/hadoop/zookeeper/conf$ 2013-08-27 12:06:16,688 - INFO  [main:QuorumPeerConfig@90] - Reading configuration from: /usr/local/hadoop/zookeeper/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
2013-08-27 12:06:16,692 - WARN  [main:QuorumPeerMain@105] - Either no config or no quorum defined in config, running  in standalone mode
2013-08-27 12:06:16,764 - INFO  [main:QuorumPeerConfig@90] - Reading configuration from: /usr/local/hadoop/zookeeper/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
2013-08-27 12:06:16,765 - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServerMain@94] - Starting server
2013-08-27 12:06:16,780 - INFO  [main:Environment@97] - Server environment:zookeeper.version=3.3.3-1073969, built on 02/23/2011 22:27 GMT
2013-08-27 12:06:16,780 - INFO  [main:Environment@97] - Server environment:host.name=naresh-pc
2013-08-27 12:06:16,781 - INFO  [main:Environment@97] - Server environment:java.version=1.6.0_27
2013-08-27 12:06:16,781 - INFO  [main:Environment@97] - Server environment:java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
2013-08-27 12:06:16,781 - INFO  [main:Environment@97] - Server environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre
2013-08-27 12:06:16,782 - INFO  [main:Environment@97] - Server environment:java.class.path=/usr/local/hadoop/zookeeper/bin/../build/classes:/usr/local/hadoop/zookeeper/bin/../build/lib/*.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/zookeeper/bin/../zookeeper-3.3.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/zookeeper/bin/../lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/zookeeper/bin/../lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/zookeeper/bin/../src/java/lib/ivy-2.1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/zookeeper/bin/../conf::/usr/local/hadoop/hive/lib:/usr/local/hadoop/lib:/usr/local/hadoop/hive/lib/hive-contrib-0.9.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/jzmq-2.1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/ring-servlet-0.3.11.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/compojure-0.6.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/curator-client-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/ring-jetty-adapter-0.3.11.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/carbonite-1.5.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/hiccup-0.3.6.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/disruptor-2.10.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/asm-4.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/objenesis-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/junit-3.8.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/clout-0.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/libthrift7-0.7.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/minlog-1.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/tools.logging-0.2.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/tools.cli-0.2.2.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/joda-time-2.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/tools.macro-0.1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/clj-time-0.4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/snakeyaml-1.9.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/commons-exec-1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/httpcore-4.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/commons-io-1.4.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/httpclient-4.1.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/reflectasm-1.07-shaded.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/zookeeper-3.3.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/math.numeric-tower-0.0.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/jgrapht-0.8.3.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/kryo-2.17.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/clojure-1.4.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/ring-core-0.3.10.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/guava-13.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/core.incubator-0.1.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/storm-0.8.1.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/storm/conf/storm.yaml
2013-08-27 12:06:16,782 - INFO  [main:Environment@97] - Server environment:java.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/client:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/../lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/client:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386:/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/i386-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
2013-08-27 12:06:16,782 - INFO  [main:Environment@97] - Server environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
2013-08-27 12:06:16,782 - INFO  [main:Environment@97] - Server environment:java.compiler=<NA>
2013-08-27 12:06:16,782 - INFO  [main:Environment@97] - Server environment:os.name=Linux
2013-08-27 12:06:16,783 - INFO  [main:Environment@97] - Server environment:os.arch=i386
2013-08-27 12:06:16,783 - INFO  [main:Environment@97] - Server environment:os.version=3.2.0-49-generic-pae
2013-08-27 12:06:16,783 - INFO  [main:Environment@97] - Server environment:user.name=hduser
2013-08-27 12:06:16,783 - INFO  [main:Environment@97] - Server environment:user.home=/home/hduser
2013-08-27 12:06:16,783 - INFO  [main:Environment@97] - Server environment:user.dir=/usr/local/hadoop/zookeeper/conf
2013-08-27 12:06:16,829 - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServer@663] - tickTime set to 2000
2013-08-27 12:06:16,830 - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServer@672] - minSessionTimeout set to -1
2013-08-27 12:06:16,830 - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServer@681] - maxSessionTimeout set to -1
2013-08-27 12:06:16,911 - INFO  [main:NIOServerCnxn$Factory@143] - binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181
2013-08-27 12:06:17,013 - INFO  [main:FileSnap@82] - Reading snapshot /usr/local/hadoop/zookeeper/snapshot/version-2/snapshot.10e27
2013-08-27 12:06:17,139 - INFO  [main:FileTxnSnapLog@208] - Snapshotting: 10e27
```

**while stopping**

```
JMX enabled by default
Using config: /usr/local/hadoop/zookeeper/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Stopping zookeeper ... 
error: could not find file /usr/local/hadoop/zookeeper/snapshot
# The number of snapshots to retain in dataDir/zookeeper_server.pid
```

Comment: Make sure you have done configured HBase properly and have proper directory permissions.

Comment: Yes, i am sure i have done configuration correctly along with the proper permission. Could you please tell me the reason of atleast issue 1? I have given rwx recursively to the datadir folder also changed the owner. But, still it is not able to create myid file in that folder.

Comment: Show me your log file.

Comment: i have updated my question with the logs of zookeeper.